# git checkout a version before a specific commit

Tags: git, github

I would like to checkout a version of a branch of a git repository before a specific commit was done. Just wondering about the syntax.

I know how to checkout a branch called 'develop' (as opposed to the master) by using the following syntax:

```
git remote add -t develop -f origin https://github.com/xy/xy.git
```

Just wondering how i can checkout this but before a specific commit was done a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 3):

After you clone the repository, run a `git log` and find the commit hash of the commit you want to checkout. You only need the first 6 characters, so it will be something like `a93fh67`. From there, run

```
git checkout {hash}
```

Where `{hash}` is the commit hash you found. That will place you in a `DETACHED HEAD` state, where you can review the code. If you want to make changes, checkout a new branch using

```
git checkout -b MyNewBranchName
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a specific commit's *parent*, which generally would be done using `^`, e.g. `abcd123^`. For merge commits it may be useful to list all parents using something like `git show abcd123^@`.

Comment: I did a remote add instead of a clone- but i dont see the difference. and then when i ran git log - i got the following error: "fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD' "

Comment: @Chris you are correct. I was assuming he would check the logs and find the commit that is the parent of the "specific commit", but he could find the "specific commit" and use the `^` syntax.

Comment: @audreykropic Did you do the remote add on a bare repository? You probably need to `git fetch`.